# python + django + ftp app .. processing files , indexing and download

Tags: python, django, ftp, ftplib

i have question regarding building a django app very simple,
its getting the username and password from the user of their accounts in ftp,
my app will retrieve the list of files, 
he can order the file by modified, by name etc..
and download the file

there is a tool ftptool 0.5.1
but the problem i can't find a way to get the file info like when created ?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftptool/0.5.1

any solution?

```
>> a_host.listdir("/a_dir")
(['other_dir', 'some_dir'], ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation and the source fo ftptools there seems to be no way of getting meta information on files unless you download them.

Using the low level ftplib that python includes, there is a FTP Protocol command `MLSD` which could be the one you are looking for. You might have to check though, if your FTP server supports that